# get list of events associated with a DOM elements

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, chrome-devtools-protocol

In Firefox it is possible to see events associated with each element in Inspect Element of developers tools.
[image]

I want to have a list of elements and events associated with it, **programmatically**. preferably using selenium+python.

I know that there is `getEventListeners` function that can be used in developer tools of Chrome, but it is not accessible in Selenium.

I went through most of the solutions offered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node-when-debugging-or-from-the-javascript), but found nothing to resolve my problem.

My ultimate goal is to iterate throw html elements of a given page and execute each element's events.

Comment: Out of interest, is this a test? What are you testing?

Comment: @Jacob well, it is not really a test. As a part of a project, I need to track DOM changes after each event executed.

Comment: Could you show us the url of the page.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA it could be any url.

Comment: Why not use puppeteer?

Comment: @mkkhedawat would you please show me some sample code that does what I asked for using puppeteer.

Comment: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3618#issuecomment-469706603

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this to a certain extent with python + selenium (chrome only):

```
body = driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Runtime.evaluate", {"expression": "document.body"})
listeners = driver.execute_cdp_cmd("DOMDebugger.getEventListeners", {"objectId": body["result"]["objectId"]})
```

Comment: I can approve that this solution works _to a certain extent_. It doesn't retrieve `React` events, for example.

Answer (score 0):

To whom it may concern, in the future!

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62370526/567073) offered by @pguardiario collects most of the events, but not `React` and `jQuery`, as far as I tested this solution.

To overcome this problem and collect `React` and `jQuery` events I dug deep into `firefox` source code and found out that `firefox` uses sort of a [parser](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/80a3d06820b31e1d95beb582f15e789cda9f6e03/devtools/server/actors/inspector/event-collector.js), to show `React` and `jQuery` events, same as [Visual Events 2](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2) solution.